# Pass dynamic value to class parameters

Tags: javascript, class

I have a variable which changes its value on click. I also pass this variable to parameters of the class. Depending on this value, some functions in the class can return different values.

However, I know that the instance is called only once, and despite of changing the variable's value, no functions inside the class are called, hence nothing happens on the page. Here is my code:

class.js

```
export default class MyClass {
    constructor(params, uniqueId) {
        this.params = {
            ...params,
        };
        ...
        this.init();
     }
       init() {
            doSomethingHere();
       }
       doSomethingHere() {
            alert(this.params.myMode);
       };
}
```

app.hbs

```
<button class="foo">foo</button>
<button class="bar">bar</button>
```

app.js

```
import MyClass from './components/MyClass';

const myMode = 'foo';

const myParams = {
  myMode,
};

new MyClass(myParams);

// by clicking buttons I can change myMode's value
document.querySelector('.foo').addEventListener('click', () => changeMapMode('foo'));
document.querySelector('.bar').addEventListener('click', () => changeMapMode('bar'));

function changeMode(value) {
    myMode = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use object instead of string, that could be solved. For example:

**app.js**

```js
import MyClass from './components/MyClass';

const myParams = {
  mode: 'foo',
};

new MyClass(myParams);

// by clicking buttons I can change myMode's value
document.querySelector('.foo').addEventListener('click', () => changeMapMode('foo'));
document.querySelector('.bar').addEventListener('click', () => changeMapMode('bar'));

function changeMode(value) {
    myParams.mode = value;
}
```

**class.js**

```js
//...
constructor(params, uniqueId) {
   this.params = params;
   //...
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to do something when `mode` changes, you need to add listeners or manage states manually. Or call functions directly immediately after change states.

Like this:

**app.js**

```js
const myClass = new MyClass(myParams);
myClass.doSomethingHere();


function changeMode(value) {
  myParams.mode = value;
  myClass.doSomethingHere();
}
```

Comment: I changed my code and can see that by clicking on the buttons, myParams.mode changes its value. However, nothing changes on the page. Can I call instance of the class again after variable changed its value? Is it a good practise if so?

Comment: Ah, okay. Got it now. Thanks a lot!